Why is ethanol used?
In some organic reactions, espcecially those of haloalkanes, we often require a ethanolic solution in the reaction conditions. However, despite me searching everywhere, I cannot find a definitive answer for why this is. Consider the reaction of sodium hydroxide, depending on whether the sodium hydroxide is ethanolic or aqueous, an alkene or an alcohol is formed. How does ethanol cause this difference? I have seen answers that say the ethanol is used as a solvent as some haloalkanes are not soluble in water. Is this correct? I have seen answers that say that ethanol somehow impacts an equilbrium. In these reactions, does ethanol participate in the mechanism?

Plenty of haloalkanes, probably most, are immiscible with water and the reaction doesn't go well if there is restricted contact between the haloalkane and the base.
